# groovy trigger compatible with jenkins for specific day of the month

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create triggers in groovy for specific day of the month ( every 3rd thursday of the month) but there seems to be compatibility issues with os cron and jenkins trigger.

Could you please suggest any possible way to achieve this in jenkins? or do we have any plugin in jenkins to schieve this.

Sample looks like (screenshot attached)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNlNg.png)

I tried 4#3 for DayOfWeek , but it throwed error not valid format.

I tried 4#3 for DayOfWeek , but it throwed error not valid format.